# bitbucket hook to run update script on remote server

Tags: git, bitbucket, hook

I am trying to achieve a specific task. I want clients to be able to access my bitbucket repository, and upon a commit/push, a shell script on a remote server will automatically pull/update from the bitbucket repository.

My issue is that I do not know how to use bitbucket's hooks in order to make the remote server run the shell script. Would I use one of the post-receive hooks? Or would I use a webhook?

Comment: Are you asking about Bitbucket Cloud (bitbucket.org) or Bitbucket Server (self-hosted)?

Comment: Hi Jim, I am pretty sure that I am running a bitbucket server, because the online repositories are not hosted on bitbucket.org. I have admin access to the hooks and web hooks, but I am completely lost on how to use them.